# tinymce editor remove for some textarea

Tags: zend-framework, tinymce, mootools, socialengine

I have couple of textarea. I am trying to remove tinymce for some textarea except one textarea.

I am using following code snippet to remove tinymce.

```
    window.addEvent('load', function(){
      $$('textarea[id^="fields-"],textarea[id^="classified_photo_"]').each(function(item){
          tinyMCE.execCommand('mceFocus', false, item.get('id'));
          tinyMCE.execCommand("mceRemoveControl", false, item.get('id'));
          tinyMCE.triggerSave();
      })
    });
```

After using this the code snippet I found that it is removing tinymce but adding some html tag may be from tinymce.[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciable.

Comment: why you dont edit your html template?

Comment: @itskawsar because it's coming from social engine view helper core file and I don't want to change core files. Thanks

Comment: in social engine they used smarty template engine. you should check it out. template files are with tpl extension. :)

Comment: @itskawsar no social engine doesn't use smarty. When social engine init front controller at bootstrap it just sets its view suffix to tpl which is by default phtml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using social engine and I don't wanted to change my core helpers after seeing the code I find the following solution which make some selected textarea as tinymce editor and the remaining textarea remains same,

```
$form = new Engine_Form();

$form->addElement('Tinymce', 'birthdate', array('editorOptions' => array('theme_advanced_buttons1' => array('undo', 'redo', 'cleanup', 'removeformat', 'pasteword', '|', 'code',
  'media', 'image', 'link', 'fullscreen', 'preview'), 'editor_selector' => 'mceEditor')))->setAttrib('class', 'mceEditor');
$form->birthdate->setAttrib('class', 'mceEditor');
```

Here editorOptions array key sets tinymce configs.

Answer (score 0):

The html source elements(in your case textareas) will become valid again, after you shut down a tinymce instance.

Comment: Thariama thanks for your reply my problem is after I remove control of tinymce it still shows html tags when I go to the textarea source code I see only text without html which isn't showing there.

Comment: are you sure what you see is really a textares and not some other kind of html element (in this case the brwoeser will render the html abnd you will only see the text content). you may use firebug to find out if you got palin text or a rendered html structure

Comment: Thariama I am not sure whether that is textarea or not but as I inspect source code I don't see tinymce editor's code anymore. Thanks for your response.